# Linhas da tabela não quebram ao terminar a página - dom PDF & Laravel

Tags: laravel, dompdf

Galera, tenho uma tabela com uma quantidade de linhas muito grande e quando gero o PDF dessa página HTML com o domPDF não pula para a próxima página. Tentei alguns tutoriais aqui, só que não funcionou muito bem.

Segue a imagem do problema:
[image: Tabela com os registros]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Resultado</title>
        <link href="{{ asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
   @page { margin: 1cm; };
  </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header" style="position: fixed; height:100px;">
            <img src="{{ asset('assets/img/header_resultado.png') }}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        </header>
        <div class="container" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif!important;">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="position:absolute; top: 3cm;">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-uppercase text-center">
                    <h4><strong>RESULTADO - </strong>CAMPUS {{ $campus->nome }} - {{ $curso->nome }} - {{ $curso_polo->turno }} - {{ $curso_polo->periodo }}º PERÍODO</h4>
                </div>
                <br>
                <h4><strong>CANDIDATOS CLASSIFICADOS ATÉ O LIMITE DE VAGAS</strong></h4>
                @php
                    $cont_1 = 1;
                    $cont_2 = count($resultado_limite_vagas) + 1;
                @endphp

                @if(count($resultado_limite_vagas) != 0)
                <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">#</th>
                        <th>NOME</th>
                        <th>RG</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">NOTA</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach($resultado_limite_vagas as $rlv)
                    <tr>
                        <td width="40px" align="center">{{ $cont_1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $rlv->nome }}</td>
                        <td width="200px">{{ $rlv->rg }}</td>
                        <td width="60px" align="center">{{ $rlv->media }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @php
                        $cont_1++;
                    @endphp
                    @endforeach
                </table>
                @else
                    <small>Não há candidatos classificados até o limite de vagas</small>
                @endif
                <br><br>
                <h4><strong>CANDIDATOS CLASSIFICADOS ALÉM DO LIMITE DE VAGAS</strong></h4>

                @if(count($resultado_alem_limite_vagas) != 0)
                <table class="table" style="page-break-after: always;">
                    <tr>
                        <th width="40px" style="text-align: center;">#</th>
                        <th>NOME</th>
                        <th width="200px">RG</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">NOTA</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach($resultado_alem_limite_vagas as $ralv)
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">{{ $cont_2 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $ralv->nome }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $ralv->rg }}</td>
                        <td width="60px" align="center">{{ $ralv->media }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @php
                        $cont_2++;
                    @endphp
                    @endforeach
                </table>
                @else
                    <small>Não há candidatos classificados além do limite de vagas</small>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
// Montagem do PDF
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('publico.resultado.resultado', compact('resultado_limite_vagas', 'resultado_alem_limite_vagas', 'curso', 'campus', 'curso_polo'));

        $pdf->setPaper('A4');

        return $pdf->stream('resultado.pdf');
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Como assim? porque ele pagina automáticamente correto? o que é essa quebra de página?

Comment: Ele pagina automaticamente? Não tá fazendo isso, tem alguma configuração específica?

Comment: Ele faz isso automático, coloque seu código na sua pergunta !

Comment: Pronto, coloquei

Comment: você já tentou imprimir o PDF desse resultado? ele não cria as paginas?

Comment: Ele cria o PDF, o problema é que quando as linhas ultrapassam o tamanho da página a4 não é gerada uma nova página com o restante das linhas.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66248/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-fellipe-botelho).

Comment: Cara, descobri o problema. Só tireo o style="position:absolute; top: 3cm;" e funfou.

Comment: Qual foi o pacote utilizado?

Comment: Você fala a library? Usei o dom PDF

Comment: Nome do pacote?

Comment: Provavelmente é alguma "DIV" ou outro tipo de tag sem fechar, verifique o código e feche a TAG aberta